# multiple login integration (google, yahoo, Facebook etc) - templates?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, yahoo

Are there any php templates out there that I could simply integrate to my site, so that my users can either login and create new accounts using their google, yahoo, fb etc account or associate existing accounts with one of the services?

Comment: oh, you want me to put forth more effort?

Answer (score 1):

Please read and research the following docs:

- [Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)
- [Federated Login for Google Account Users](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)
- [Yahoo! OpenID + OAuth Quick Start Guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/openid-oauth-guide.html)

Here's also a very good OpenID PHP library to get you started:

http://gitorious.org/lightopenid